# best way to toggle between functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I see different topics about the toggle function in jquery, but what is now really the best way to toggle between functions?
Is there maybe some way to do it so i don't have to garbage collect all my toggle scripts?

Some of the examples are:

```
var first=true;
function toggle() {
   if(first) {
      first= false;
      // function 1
   }
   else {
      first=true;
      // function 2
   }
}
```

And

```
var first=true;
function toggle() {
   if(first) {
      // function 1
   }
   else {
      // function 2
   }
first = !first;
}
```

And

```
var first=true;
function toggle() {
  (first) ? function_1() : function_2();
  first != first;
}
function function_1(){}
function function_2(){}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "some way to do it so i don't have to garbage collect all my toggle scripts"?

Comment: @phant0m Sometimes in large project i have allot of toggle scripts and use global variables to determine if it is toggled or not. So those variables needs to garbage collect for organizing variables, like if i maybe use the same variable name somehow or things like that

Comment: Unless you have thousands of them, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

return an new function

```
var foo = (function(){
    var condition
         , body
    body = function () {
        if(condition){
             //thing here
        } else {
            //other things here
        }
    }
    return body
}())`
```

Answer (score 0):

Best really depends on the criteria your application demands. This might not be the best way to this is certainly a cute way to do it:

```
function toggler(a, b) {
   var current;
   return function() {
      current = current === a ? b : a;
      current();
   }
}

var myToggle = toggler(function_1, function_2);
myToggle(); // executes function_1
myToggle(); // executes function_2
myToggle(); // executes function_1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but i'd like to contribute too..

> Sometimes in large project i have allot of toggle scripts and use global variables to determine if it is toggled or not. So those variables needs to garbage collect for organizing variables, like if i maybe use the same variable name somehow or things like that

You could try something like this..: *(using your first example)*

```
function toggle() {
    var self = arguments.callee;
    if (self.first === true) {
        self.first = false;
        // function 1
    }
    else {
        self.first = true;
        // function 2
    }
}
```

Without a global variable. I just added the property `first` to the function scope.
This way can be used the same property name for other toggle functions too.

**Warning:** `arguments.callee` is forbidden in 'strict mode'

---

Otherwise you may directly assign the `first` property to the function using directly the function name

```
function toggle() {
    if (toggle.first === true) {
        toggle.first = false;
        // function 1
    }
    else {
        toggle.first = true;
        // function 2
    }
}
```